# How to optimize typical functions in jquery (mouseover/mouseout)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I write code to open some part of page when hovering other part.

```
...
$(".window-one").mouseover(function() {$(".window-one-modal").removeClass("def-visible");});
$(".window-one").mouseout(function() {$(".window-one-modal").addClass("def-visible");});

$(".window-two").mouseover(function() {$(".window-two-modal").removeClass("def-visible");});
$(".window-two").mouseout(function() {$(".window-two-modal").addClass("def-visible");});

$(".window-three").mouseover(function() {$(".window-three-modal").removeClass("def-visible");});
$(".window-three").mouseout(function() {$(".window-three-modal").addClass("def-visible");});
...
```

But I have a lot of element to hovering and to display, so I get a lot of typical code. How I can optimize it?

Comment: The best way to DRY this up would depend on how the HTML is structured. Could you please add a sample of that to the question.

Comment: Its two independents parts of page. First have blocks to hover, and second use to display modals. And .def-visible have property display:none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you state the two HTML structures are in separate sections of the DOM one way to DRY this up would be to put a common class on all the `.window-X` elements and use a `data` attribute to specify their target modal. From there you can use a single `hover()` call and the `toggleClass()` method. Try this:

```js
var $modals = $('.modal');

$(".window").hover(function() {
  $modals.filter($(this).data('target')).toggleClass("def-visible");
});
```

```css
.def-visible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="window" data-target="#modal-one">Hover Me</div>
<div class="window" data-target="#modal-two">Hover Me</div>
<div class="window" data-target="#modal-three">Hover Me</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="modal def-visible" id="modal-one">Modal one</div>
<div class="modal def-visible" id="modal-two">Modal two</div>
<div class="modal def-visible" id="modal-three">Modal three</div>
```

One note here is that `toggle()` uses the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. The former is preferable over `mouseover` as it only fires once when the mouse enters the element's position which gives better performance in this case.

It may also be possible to do this in CSS alone, but that would entirely depend on how the modals relate to the hovered elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this more readable format:

```js
$('div[class^="window"]')
  .mouseover(function() {
    toggleDefVisible(this)
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    toggleDefVisible(this)
  });

function toggleDefVisible(el) {
  $(el).find('[class^="window"]').toggleClass("def-visible");
}
```

```css
.def-visible {
  background-color: gray;
}

div[class^="window-"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="window-one"><span class="window-one-modal def-visible">ONE</span></div>
<div class="window-two"><span class="window-two-modal def-visible">TWO</span></div>
<div class="window-three"><span class="window-three-modal def-visible">THREE</span></div>
```